# How to avoid msvcr100.dll dependency when manipulating files?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am writing a custom installer launcher in C which opens, reads and writes files. I use `fopen()` to open the files. This works perfectly on Linux and the binary does not depend on libstdc++.so but on Windows in Visual Studio 2010 I get a dependency on MSVCR100.DLL. If I add the `/NODEFAULTLIB` flag the linker fails.

I need this program to be free of the MSVCR100.DLL dependency since it launches an installer which at a later stage installs the VC++ 2010 Redistributable and at the time of the launch it is not sure if the host machine has this library.

How can I manipulate files in VS without MSVCR100.DLL?

Comment: While your program in Linux doesn't depend on libstdc++ it's because you're programming in C and libstdc++ is for C++. However, your program *do* depend on libc (glibc), which is installed by default on just about all Linux distributions. As for your Windows version, it needs runtime support as well, all the standard C functions that on Linux is found in libc, on Windows they are in the MSVCR100 library. To solve the problem you should not link dynamically to the runtime library, but link *statically*. Your program will be a lot bigger, but it will not need the external runtime library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the dependency to msvcr100.dll (and probably msvcp100.dll) because your project settings define this. You should use static linking instead of dynamic linking of the runtime library.

Change your `C/C++ code generation settings`: Runtime Library. Select an option without DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you can change your code a bit, you can use the Win32 API (CreateFile, ReadFile...). This will link to kernel32.dll, which is always available.